# The slider created by jQuery and Slick Slider, itself changes its width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

When I changed "fade" on false the slider changed its width and "max-width" don't work

I tried to paste "max-width", but it dont help. Also, i tried to find some properties but none helped.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-slider]").slick({
        infinite: true,
        fade: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Please have a closer look at the editor toolbar and format your code properly. Also see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.